# Is this proof for $e^{i\pi}=-1$ correct?

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, alternative-proof

So, I know there is a post that already asks this question, but the question I’m asking is if my proof ,up to now, is correct, and how to finish it. I have not studied sin and cos, so please refrain from using those in your answer.

So, if we break it down, $e^{i\pi}=i^2=-1$. If we replaced the values in this equation by, say, 2, 3 and x, then we get $2^{3x}=3^2=9$ To get 9, we need to find $\frac {log_2(9)}{3}$, which is equal to about $1.056641667$. If we replace $x$ by this new number, then we get $2^{3\times1.056641667}$, which is roughly equal to $9$. Now, going back to $e^{i\pi}$, we can apply the same strategy. We need to find $\frac{log_e(\pi)}{i}$. $log_e(\pi)$ is easy, it’s about 1.144729886. I’m just wondering how to get $\frac {1.144729886}{i}$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77111/discussion-on-question-by-detmondyou-is-this-proof-for-ei-pi-1-correct).

Comment: All future commenters are encouraged to check whether what they want to say was already said. Some were harping on the OP's misuse of "equation" when they meant identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very difficult to formulate a proof of this without the use of $\sin$ and $\cos$, so I will do my best to explain every usage of it.

The [Taylor Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) of $e^y=1+y+\frac{y^2}{2!}+\frac{y^3}{3!}+...$

Applying $y=ix$ we get $e^{ix}=1+ix-\frac{x^2}{2!}-\frac{ix^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+...$

Here is where $\sin$ and $\cos$ come into play. Their Taylor Expansions are:
$$\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2x}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\frac{x^6}{6!}+...$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+...$$

This means that $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$ by inspection.

$$\to e^{i\pi}=\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi)$$
Looking [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a1pvp7yqhh) you will see that $\cos(\pi)=-1$ and $\sin(\pi)=0$.

Hence $e^{i\pi}=-1+0i=-1$.